# Is there anything like Material-UI Autocomplete freeSolo in the React-Admin AutocompleteInput

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I am using React-Admin and I know that React-Admin is using Material-UI but I couldn't find something like [Material-UI Autocomplete freeSolo](https://material-ui.com/ru/components/autocomplete/#free-solo). Actually I am after a kind of AutocompleteInput that doesn't force me to choose an element. freeSolo is working like that.

I just wanted to make sure that if this does not exist in React-Admin, then I create a new element.

Currently, I know that I can define AutocompleteInput with my custom choices like this:

```
const choices = [
  { id: 123, first_name: 'Leo', last_name: 'Tolstoi' },
  { id: 456, first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'Austen' },
];
const optionRenderer = choice => `${choice.first_name} ${choice.last_name}`;
<AutocompleteInput choices={choices} optionText={optionRenderer} />
```

But because of too many choices, I have to fetch data from my RESTful web service. It also does not let me put my custom text (a text that does not exist in the list) inside the text input. I mean after the Autocomplete suggestions disappeared, the text input gets cleared.

I tried to use:

```
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
```

but "Autocomplete" was not there. The `@material-ui/lab` just includes `AutocompleteArrayInput` and `AutocompleteInput`. I also installed the `@material-ui/core` but it doesn't let me use that.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the package, what package manager do you use?

Comment: I installed the `@material-ui/core` and the `Autocomplete` was added. I also tried `AutoComplete` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutoComplete` is not part of `@material-ui/core` it is in `@material-ui/lab`, you need to install that.

You also need to make sure that you have the appropriate version of `@material-ui/lab`

This solution varies, depending on the package manager you are using to install.

If you are using yarn:
you can upgrade to the latest version of the package (there will be some breaking changes there)

```
yarn upgrade @material-ui/lab --latest
```

If you are using npm:

```
npm install @material-ui/lab@latest
```

Make sure you understand the use of `lab`, in some point this feature will move to core and you will need to adjust yourself to it. You might need to use the `latest` flags to force the package manager to update and ignore the breaking changes.

Comment: Thank you. I installed the `@material-ui/lab` and it solved my issue.
I am using `npm` and `npm i @material-ui/lab` solved the issue.

Comment: I tried but stackoverflow prevents me by this issue:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302885/when-reputation-is-15-do-previously-cast-votes-get-displayed

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that with AutocompleteInput because it is a component limited to filtering.

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Inputs.md#writing-your-own-input-component):

> Tip: AutocompleteInput is a stateless component, so it only **allows to filter the list of choices, not to extend it**. If you need to populate the list of choices based on the result from a fetch call (and if  doesn't cover your need), you'll have to write your own Input component based on material-ui  component.

Comment: Thank you @fjplaurr. I found a reported issue that  itseems like mine but not exactly:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2428